# How does the theme folder work in drupal 7?

Tags: theming

In Drupal 7, I would disable a theme within the admin section and i would physically rename the theme directory (from themeName to themeName_old), clear cache and restart the server, to my surprise, drupal 7 still picks up the theme (themeName_old).

The only only way i managed to get rid of a theme completely is by removing the the directory from the theme folder. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Folder name does not matter. What matters is name of the info file. If you have `themeName.info` in folder, Drupal knows it's a folder for a theme named *themeName*.

Comment: Thx @molot but what is the purpose of disabling the theme in the drupal admin section?

Comment: @winteck to make users unable to select it, if you will allow them theme selection? Things like that. What's your problem?

Comment: I thought that "disable a theme" meant that it was no longer accessible in the front end. But i got it now, I did read about it in the docs, but it only makes sense now , i guess it is the "drupal way". so thx again...